# MMSE Community Promotion Board

Tags: discussion, sponsorship-and-advertising, community

Taking the suggestion from Geoff Hutchison in [Highlighting Matsci.org forum - community promotions](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/highlighting-matsci-org-forum-community-promotions), I decided to put together an MMSE page for community ads. Simply add an answer with a title, a brief description, and a link to whatever project your advertising (and ideally an image to go with the ad so that these can be converted to SE Community Ads if/when this feature is extended to our site).

My hope is to leave this fairly open ended in terms of what people want to advertise, but to just give some examples of things I feel would be a good fit to promote:

- Upcoming conferences, lectures, or online courses
- New forums of interest to Matter Modelers, both on and off the SE network
- Lesser known software or computer programs used in modeling
- Books or lecture notes on matter modeling topics
- Citizen Science projects or large scale community research efforts

Answer (score 3):

## Material Science Community Discourse

[image: A forum for various Material Science computer programs]

Collection of forums for all things Materials Science. Divided up into categories by topic/program for ease of searching. Some notable subforums for topics that have also had questions on MMSE include LAMMPS, The Materials Project, ASE, and pymatgen.

I think it would be beneficial to have collaboration with this site. We have included RSS feeds for some of the subforums in the relevant [chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=mattermodeling.stackexchange.com) on our site.

Comment: Since MSCD and MMSE are "competing" Q/A sites, it would seem fair that we help advertise them if they help advertise us too. The comment chain [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9938/5) got me thinking about this.